# Automatic Currency Conversion From USD to BTC Using blockchain.com URL

Tags: woocommerce, currency, data-conversion, bitcoin, price

The idea is very simple since the URL automatically updates the price itself, all I need is to add the BTC price within brackets.

Example: `0.00003573` is the result from using this URL:

https://www.blockchain.com/tobtc?currency=USD&value=1

But, something is wrong and I am not sure how to fix it. I get "`Warning: A non-numeric value`". I need to display the output from the URL based on the product price.

**This is the code I am working with:**

```php
function manual_currency_conversion( $price ) {
    $btc_conversion_rate = "https://www.blockchain.com/tobtc?currency=USD&value=1"; // returns this: 0.00003573 = which will auto update automatically
    $btc_price = (float) $price / $btc_conversion_rate;

    return number_format( $btc_price, 8, '.', '' );
}
    
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'btc_additional_currency', 10, 5 );
function btc_additional_currency( $return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price, $original_price = null ) {
    $display_btc_price = manual_currency_conversion( $price );
    $btc_currency = '₿';
    $currency_symbol = $btc_currency;
    $display_btc_price = $currency_symbol . $display_btc_price;
    $btc_price_on_product_page = '<small><span class="btc-price"> ( ' . $display_btc_price . ' ) </small></span>';

    return $return . $btc_price_on_product_page;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer code… Now the price is sent via the URL to get directly the BTC price (and the function also allow other currencies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated *(Also allow other currencies and default currency is taken from settings)*

To avoid this issue, you need to use [`file_get_contents()` PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php) with your URL to get effectively the desired data.

Also, the rate needs to be multiplied with the price to get the correct converted price (instead of a division).

I have revised and simplified your code:

```php
function get_btc_price_from( $price, $currency_from = '' ) {
    $currency_from = empty( $currency_from ) ? get_option('woocommerce_currency') : $currency_from;
    $btc_rate = file_get_contents("https://www.blockchain.com/tobtc?currency={$currency_from}&value=1");
    return number_format( floatval($btc_rate) * floatval($price), 8, '.', '' );
}
    
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'btc_additional_currency', 10, 2 );
function btc_additional_currency( $price_html, $price ) {
    return $price_html . '<small class="btc-price"> ( ₿'. get_btc_price_from( $price, 'USD' ). ' )</small>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

Example usage with EUROS:

```php
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'btc_additional_currency', 10, 2 );
function btc_additional_currency( $price_html, $price ) {
    return $price_html . '<small class="btc-price"> ( ₿'. get_btc_price_from( $price, 'EUR' ). ' )</small>';
}
```

Example usage with Default WooCommerce currency:

```php
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'btc_additional_currency', 10, 2 );
function btc_additional_currency( $price_html, $price ) {
    return $price_html . '<small class="btc-price"> ( ₿'. get_btc_price_from( $price ). ' )</small>';
}
```

Comment: If at all possible, it would be be even better if it took the currency used by WC (get_option?) and then allowed for an array to define additional currencies.

Ex: the site uses USD, but by uisng an array, you can add EUR and others ads well. Meaning, it would woild convert 2, 3, 4 och evne 5 currencies.

Could you make that update to the code?

Comment: Sorry, so you mean by adding `return $price_html . '<small class="btc-price"> ( ₿'. get_btc_price_from( $price, 'EUR' ). ' )</small>';` I could add `$price, 'EUR', 'USD' etc etc ?

Comment: Now it takes the currency from WooCommerce (if no currency is specified).

Comment: Ok, because using the original version works fine, but using the new version gives me "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error ".

Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: For me, it was working… I have reverted the code a little bit.

Comment: Ok, I'll go with the first option since no other currencies are shown if adding more than one one to this line: `return $price_html . '<small class="btc-price"> ( ₿'. get_btc_price_from( $price, 'EUR', 'AUS' ). ' )</small>';` 

Either way, thanks you for helping and for providing an answer on how to make it work with the default WC compared to BTC.